# VBA code to unhide tabs based on a list with if criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code below which unhides the sheets if they appear in a list between B4 and B35 on a tab called "Cost Tracking". 
I need to add a kind of "if" statement that if in the adjacent 2nd column to the right it says "reserved" then don't unhide it, otherwise unhide it. I think the If code I need is ...

```
If UCase$(Nm.Offset(0, 2).Value) <> "RESERVED" Then
If UCase$(Nm.Offset(0, 1).Value) <> "2" Then
```

however I am a bit confused how to include it within the code. Is there also a way to stop the second click of the button from re-hiding everything, presumably that's something I've accidentally set up within the code. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Button5_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim shList As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cost Tracking")
    shList = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("b4:b35"))

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, shList, 0)) Then
            sh.Visible = Not sh.Visible
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub Button5_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim m As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.workSheets("Cost Tracking")

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.workSheets
        m = Application.Match(sh.Name, ws.Range("b4:b35"), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            sh.Visible = cbool(lcase(ws.cells(m+3, "D").value2) <> "reserved")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you Jeeped that code runs with no errors which is great but it still unhides those that say "reserved"

Comment: In an unused column to the right, put this formula into the 4th row `=d4="reserved"` and fill down to row 35. Do the cells in D4:D35 actually say "reserved"?

Comment: Yes that comes back as true for some of the rows. Some say "reserved" others have the names of tabs, so it's just the ones with names I want to unhide but currently it unhides all (including "reserved" row sheet names)

Comment: Your code above says that the worksheet names are in column B and the reserved annotations are in column D. Here you say they are in the same column.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that very well, sheet names are all in B and have the names of the tabs which are all numbers 011, 012, 013, in column D are the descriptions of these sheets which are for example, pneumatics, controls, reserved. It's only the reserved I want to leave hidden which belongs in column D, however tab names are in column B.

Comment: oh-key-doh-key, my bad. I forgot to adjust the row number returned by the match by the starting row of the match range. I've added 3 to m above.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use it like this

```
If UCase$(Nm.Offset(0, 2).Value) <> "RESERVED" Then
    sh.Visible = False
End If
```

Note that `sh.Visible = Not sh.Visible` toggles the visibility while `sh.Visible = False` hides the worksheet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. When I add that to the code I get an object required error on the  line                                                                                     If UCase$(Nm.Offset(0, 2).Value) <> "RESERVED" Then